# What is a fastest way to get words from T-SQL datatable?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datatable

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 datatable `dbo.Forum_Posts` with columns `Subject (nvarchar(255))` and`Body (nvarchar(max))`.

I would like to get all words with length >= 3 from columns `Subject` and `Body` and insert them into datatable `dbo.Search_Word (column Word, nvarchar(100))` and datatable `dbo.SearchItem (column Title (nvarchar(200))`.

I also want to get new generated `SearchWordsID (primary key, autoincrement, int)` from `dbo.Search_Word`, and `SearchItemID (primary key, autoincrement,int)` from `dbo.SearchItem`, and insert them into datatable `dbo.SearchItemWord (columns SearchWordsID (foreign key,int, not null)` and `SearchItemID (foreign key,int,not null)`.

What is a fastest way to do this in T-SQL? Or I have to use C#? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: While you COULD use T-SQL, recall it works on the relational set theory. Why not pull the data via T-SQL and parse words using C#? C#,which builds on C++ and other languages is a cursive language, so performance it should be faster to implement. But if you want to use SQL, make sure Full-Text is on. Alternately, check out [FREETEXT - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Unfortunately, I should use T-SQL as a solution.

Comment: Last comment: so you know, I am speaking about making a useful, consistent, accurate list. Is this was handtyped, I sure hope your not using it for anything that important. Errors will likely exist.

Comment: Thank you again for your time and attention. Best regards, alenan2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, this will keep the ID's.  So you will get a DISTINCT list of works BY id.

Slightly different approach than the first answer, but easily achieved via the Outer Apply

**

> **You must edit the initial query  Select KeyID=[YourKeyID],Words=[YourField1]+' '+[YourField2] from [YourTable]**

**

```
Declare @String    varchar(max) = ''
Declare @Delimeter varchar(25)  = ' '

-- Generate and Strip special characters
Declare @StripChar table (Chr varchar(10));Insert Into @StripChar values ('.'),(','),('/'),('('),(')'),(':')  -- Add/Remove as needed

-- Generate Base Data and Expand via Outer Apply
Declare @XML xml
Set @XML = (
            Select A.KeyID
                  ,B.Word
             From ( Select KeyID=[YourKeyID],Words=[YourField1]+' '+[YourField2] from [YourTable]) A
             Outer Apply (
                          Select Word=split.a.value('.', 'varchar(150)') 
                           From  (Select Cast ('<x>' + Replace(A.Words, @Delimeter, '</x><x>')+ '</x>' AS XML) AS Data) AS A 
                           Cross Apply data.nodes ('/x') AS Split(a)
             ) B
 For XML RAW)

-- Convert XML to varchar(max) for Global Search & Replace (could be promoted to Outer Appy)
Select @String = Replace(Replace(cast(@XML as varchar(max)),Chr,' '),'  ',' ') From @StripChar
Select @XML    = cast(@String as XML)

Select Distinct
       KeyID = t.col.value('@KeyID', 'int')
      ,Word  = t.col.value('@Word', 'varchar(150)')
 From  @XML.nodes('/row') AS t (col)
 Where Len(t.col.value('@Word', 'varchar(150)'))>3
 Order By 1
```

Returns

```
KetID   Word
0       UNDEF
0       Undefined
1       HIER
1       System
2       Control
2       UNDEF
3       JOBCONTROL
3       Market
3       Performance
...
87      Analyitics
87      Market
87      UNDEF
88      Branches
88      FDIC
88      UNDEF
...
```

Comment: @alenan2013 Updated so you only have to edit the INITIAL query

Comment: @alenan2013  I should also add performance will be diminished compared to the 1st anwer

Comment: Thank you very much again, it works great :) I only worry about that what could happen if @XML was greater than varchar(max)?

Comment: Varchar(max) should not be confused with varchar(8000).  Varchar(max) is can store up to 2GB

Comment: Yes, ok. Best regards, alenan2013

Comment: If you have a large and growing database, execute as provided for the initial run, and then execute only new/updated threads

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need T-SQL to do the inserting into your tables. Your biggest challenge is going to be splitting the posts into words.

My suggestion would be to read the posts into C#, split each post into words (you can use the `Split` method to split on spaces or punctuation), filter the collection of words, and then execute your inserts from C#.

You can avoid using T-SQL directly if you use `Entity Framework` or a similar ORM.

Don't try to use T-SQL to split your posts into words unless you really want a totally SQL solution and are willing to take time to perfect it. And, yes, it will be slow: T-SQL is not fast at string operations.

You can also investigate full text indexing, which I believe has support for search keywords.

Comment: Thank you for your help and attention. But, as I mentioned above, I should use T-SQL as a solution (this is requested solution).

Comment: @alenan2013 I got this: is this the right solution given the constraints of your department? Can you or do you want to solve this by the more effective method? Not only will you have to parse using FULL TEXT (if you care about optimization), but you may have to build a custom library, thesaurus, and even then, implement at least a basic algorithm to handle variances, misspelling in the rows. See SOUNDEX,similar methods. Do you have a fault tolerance for accuracy/false positives? Are multiple languages involved? These and more should be asked and C#/other OOP languages should be considered...

Comment: @alenan2013 unless you simply want a list that serves a limited purpose, this may be difficult even with the right STOP WORDS. Not impossible, but hopefully you can see how at least the initial design of the list of words ought to be done in another language or prepare yourself for a lot...of finesse code writing...even if you put every word in its own row and ran a distinct/group by,  if you care about a useful list, algorithms have to be developed...btw, you did tag C#

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help

```
Declare @String varchar(max) = ''
Declare @Delimeter varchar(25)  = ' '

Select @String = @String + ' '+Words
  From (
         Select Words=[YourField1]+' '+[YourField2] from [YourTable]
       ) A

-- Generate and Strip special characters
Declare @StripChar table (Chr varchar(10));Insert Into @StripChar values ('.'),(','),('/'),('('),(')'),(':')  -- Add/Remove as needed
Select @String = Replace(Replace(@String,Chr,' '),'  ',' ') From @StripChar

-- Convert String into XML and Split Delimited String
Declare @Table Table (RowNr int Identity(1,1), String varchar(100))
Declare @XML xml = Cast('<x>' + Replace(@String,@Delimeter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as XML)
Insert Into @Table Select String.value('.', 'varchar(max)') From @XML.nodes('x') as T(String)

-- Generate Final Resuls
Select Distinct String
 From  @Table
 Where Len(String)>3
 Order By 1
```

Returns (sample)

```
    String
    ------------------
    Access
    Active
    Adminstrators
    Alternate
    Analyitics
    Applications
    Branches
    Cappelletti
    City
    Class
    Code
    Comments
    Contact
    Control
    Daily
    Data
    Date
    Definition
    Deleted
    Down
    Email
    FDIC
    Variables
    Weekly
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly.But, I have a problem that I didn't mention in my question: I should save forum post link next to each word with length > 3. The datatable with forum post links can be joined with my table dbo.Forum_Post. Would you be so kind and update your solution to save Forum Post Link next to the each word? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The field name is ForumLink, in datatable dbo.Forum_Forums.

Comment: @alenan2013 I added a second answer.  Be sure to read comments